# if condition in awk command is not working as expected in BEGIN block. correct me if am wrong

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a command like below

```
kubectl get pods |
grep -v 1/1 |
grep -v 2/2 |
awk '{print $1:$2:$3}' |
awk 'BEGIN{ print "<style>table,th,td {border:1px solid black;}
```

Sample output from `kubectl`:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      READY       STATUS              RESTARTS
ABC       ABC-jkij     1/1        RUNNING          897
BAC       BAC-jkij     2/2        RUNNING          897
HJI       HJI-jkij     2/2        RUNNING          897

kubectl get pods | grep -v 1/1 | grep -v 2/2 | awk '{print $1:$2:$3}'
```

The above command will result only the headers like below as i kept `-v`:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      READY       STATUS              RESTARTS
```

so in Awk we have no of records variable right, I want to put a condition in the Awk block which should print only if there are any 0/1 or 0/2 pod results, not just the headers.

So to summmarize

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      READY       STATUS              RESTARTS
```

--> awk should not print anything

```
NAMESPACE   NAME      READY       STATUS              RESTARTS
ABC       ABC-jkij     0/1        RUNNING               897
ABC       ABC-jkij     0/2        RUNNING               897
```

Awk should print only in above scenarios.

Above command will give the headers like `NAME NAMESPACE STATUS` as output if there are no pods in with 0/1 0/2 etc., status. Now I want to include an `if` condition saying `if (NR >1 )` then only it should print else it should not print anything ie.,  headers. If I am trying to put  `if (NR>1)` in begin block it's still printing the headers.

Comment: Please, post the output of `kubectl get pods`  and the expected output. Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks. Not my downvote, btw,

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  I'm not sure what to call `grep | grep | awk | awk | awk`; perhaps an anti-pattern on steroids.  Or an anti-anti-anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally avoid piping Awk into Awk; it's a scripting language, so you can put as many statements as you want.

```
kubectl get pods | 
awk 'NR>1 && !/1\/1|2\/2/ {
    if (!headers++) print "<style>table,th,td {border:1px solid black;}</style><table>"
    print "<tr>"
    for (i=1; i<=3; ++i) printf "<td>%s</td>\n", $i
    print "</tr>"
  }
  END { if (headers) print "</table>" }'
```

I had to guess a bit what your expected output would be but if there are glitches, I expect it should be easy to see what to fix.

Comment: Hi Triplee, thank you so much for your response but still the same.  i Updated the question & added more details. my requirement is if " get pods | grep -v "0/1" | grep -v 0/2" is returning only headers, dont print anything on console. if it is printing any pods along with headers then only print it. Hope i am clear now. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is indeed what this does, though you might need to update the regular expression which selects which lines to process. In case it's not obvious, the negated regex `!/.../` does what your double `grep` did; perhaps see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep). Now you are saying 0/1 and 0/2 but your question still says 1/1 and 2/2.

Comment: I added `NR>1` to the condition to skip the header.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks as always, it looks rather elegant now (-: